Finding subscriptions IDs for users in Microsoft 365
Does Microsoft have no way for you to look up which subscription a user has? I see that I can query the Graph API for /licenseDetails and /SubscribedSkus, but none of the information in there matches the subscription IDs that I see when I log into the 365 admin portal and look up the GUID for a subscription. It gives me the name of the license and the service plan, but not which 365 subscription ID is being used by that user.
Nothing seems to match, but I can't imagine that it's just not there.
Of course, when I go to the admin portal and click on a subscription, it shows me all of the users on that subscription, but I want to go in reverse order: given a user's ID, what subscriptions are they using?
